# How best to structure classes in a data visualization program to handle the many matplotlib keyword arguments?

Tags: python, matplotlib, keyword-argument

I'm building a data visualization program that has specific classes dedicated to plotting data in a specific ways. My question is: how is it best to handle all the matplotlib keyword arguments within a class structure to maximize both user flexibility and good coding practice?

For example lets say I have a structure like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class AverageData():
    ...methods related to plotting averages

    self.plot_averages()

class IndividualRepeats():
    ... methods related to plotting individual repeats on the same graph

    self.plot_individual_repeats()
```

In each of these classes I want to be able to change the colours, font sizes, marker styles etc. In my early programs my approach was to simply pass these arguments into the constructor such as:

```
class AverageData():
    def __init__(self,colour='k',fontsize=22):
        self.colour=colour
        self.fontsize=fontsize

        self.plot_average()

    def plot_average(self):
        plt.plot(x_data,y_data,color=self.color)
        plt.title('average plot',fontsize=self.fontsize)
```

However with as many optional arguments as `matplotlib` this quickly becomes unwieldy. An alternative approach I came up with (with help from a SO question) that I used a previous project was :

```
class AverageData():
    def __init__(self,input_data,**kwargs):
        self.input_data=input_data
        self.kwargs=kwargs


        options={'full_axes':True,
                 'style':'ggplot',
                 'linewidth'   : 1.0,     # line width in points
                 'linestyle'   : '-',       # solid line
                 'color'       : 'green',    # has no affect on plot(); see axes.prop_cycle
                 'marker'      : None,    # the default marker
                 'markeredgewidth'  : 0.5,     # the line width around the marker symbol
                 'markersize'  : 6,            # markersize, in points
                 'fontsize':22,
                 'axes_fontsize':15}     # render lines in antialiased (no jaggies)}

        for i in self.kwargs.keys():
            if i not in options.keys():
                raise Errors.InputError('{} is not a keyword argument of AverageData'.format(i)) #custom error

        self.kwargs.update(options)

        self.line_options={'linewidth':self.kwargs['linewidth'],
                       'linestyle':self.kwargs['linestyle'],
                       'color':self.kwargs['color'],
                       'marker':self.kwargs['marker'],
                       'markeredgewidth':self.kwargs['markeredgewidth'],
                       'markersize':self.kwargs['markersize']}

    def plot_average(self):
         plt.plot(x_data,y_data,**self.line_options)
```

This is better because you only have to define the default options within the `options` variable and update `kwargs`. The problem with this approach is 1) the requirement to 'sub-dictionary' the `kwargs` to get the correct keywords to the correct places and 2) when you're doing this for a lot of classes there is a lot of duplicated code.

Thanks for sticking with the (rather long) question. Looking forward to hearing your thoughts.

Comment: It may be helpful looking at how other people do this.  For example, [`pandas.tools.plotting`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/tools/plotting.py) or [`seaborn`](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/tree/master/seaborn).  As with both of these cases, I think your class `__init__`s should accept `**kwargs` where you can interact with some of them but ultimately pass the kwargs to the necessary `matplotlib` functions.

Comment: You could simply pass the kwargs on to the matplotlib plotting function. Since most plotting functions themselves have kwargs you shouldn't experience any problems. And for the few functions that don't have kwargs, you can tailor a special solution. If there is anything that prevents this approach, could you please update your question accordingly?

Comment: Hi there, the problem with trying to pass the whole  `kwarg` dict to `plt.plot` is the fact that I'll need other kwargs (such as `full_axes` and `style` here) that are not keywords for `plt.plot`. The result is an attribute error: `AttributeError: Unknown property full_axes`

Comment: Still, you could pop all your kwargs from the kwargs before passing it to plot. `full_axes = kwargs.pop("full_axes", False)`